# Inheritance problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have the following class hierarchy:

- Storage

  - Collection

    - EixoCollection
    - OfertaCollection

And I have the following code:

```
var ofertaCollection = new OfertaCollection();
var eixoCollection = new EixoCollection();

ofertaCollection.set('mykey', 'myvalue');
alert(eixoCollection.get('mykey')); // it returns 'myvalue', should return nothing
```

The problem is that ofertaCollection and eixoCollection have properties referencing each other.

Follow the classes:

```
/**
 * Storage
 * 
 * @returns {Storage}
 */
function Storage(){

    this.storage = []; // itens that have a key

    // sets key
    this.set = function(key, value){
        this.storage[key] = value;
    }

    // gets key
    this.get = function(key){
        return this.storage[key];
    }
}

/**
 * Collection
 * 
 * @returns {Collection}
 */
function Collection(){

}
Collection.prototype = new Storage();

/**
 * EixoCollection
 * 
 * @returns {EixoCollection}
 */
function EixoCollection(){
}
EixoCollection.prototype = new Collection();

/**
 * OfertaCollection
 * 
 * @returns {OfertaCollection}
 */
function OfertaCollection(){
}
OfertaCollection.prototype = new Collection();
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you even have the `Collection` class at all? Looks like serious bloat to me... all you've done is wrapped the `Storage` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest two changes in your code (that the examples will use): `this.storage` should be an object `{}`, since it looks like you never use it as an array. Also, `get` and `set` should be in the prototype, otherwise a new instance of those methods will be created for every instance object (unless a smart compiler optimises them, but we won't assume as much).

Solution 1: you could perform quasi-inheritance, whereby only your storage *methods* are given to inheriting classes, but not the storage *object*:

```
function Storage(){}
storage.prototype = {
    get: function(key){
        return this.storage[key];
    },
    set: function(key, value){
        this.storage[key] = value;
    }
};

function Collection(){
    this.storage = {};
}
Collection.prototype = Storage.prototype; // quasi-inheritance

function EixoCollection(){}
EixoCollection.prototype = new Collection();

function OfertaCollection(){}
OfertaCollection.prototype = new Collection();

var ofertaCollection = new OfertaCollection();
var eixoCollection = new EixoCollection();

ofertaCollection.set('mykey', 'myvalue');
alert(eixoCollection.get('mykey')); // undefined
```

Solution 2: Real inheritance, but instantiate a new store for every collection, so during the prototype lookup the function finds the local store. This is identical to the above, but the inheritance would be as before. So I'll just replace the line that's different:

```
Collection.prototype = new Storage(); // real inheritance
```

The problem with both of these implementations is that they require the inheriting class to do two things, both inherit the methods, and instantiate a store. Not pretty.

The easy alternative, and maybe the most intuitive one is to make each use of `Storage` a composite object, and not an inherited one. A collection *has an* internal storage, and some extra functionalities, so it fulfils the *has-a* mnemonic making composition a valid candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both of your collection objects share the same `Storage` object.

```
var c1 = new OfteraCollection().prototype.prototype;
var c2 = new ExioCollection().prototype.prototype;
console.log(c1 === c2); // true
```

To remedy this, you could ditch `Collection` all together and have each one of your collection objects create their own `Storage` as their prototype.

Comment: I amended my answer, but I am still curious. Why are you doing this? Do you have other methods for your objects? From what I see, all you really need to do is say `var coll = new Object(); coll[key] = value;`

Comment: Yes, I have. I only show that way to minify the code =). And I dont understand the amended answer, could you give a example? (newbie in js =p)

Comment: I can't right now, but read this in the meantime: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "create their own `Storage` as their prototype." If all you did was remove the `Collection` layer, then each type (if it's instantiating its prototype as `new Storage()`) would still suffer from the shared memory issue, and multiple instances of a single type wouldn't be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the very quick fix - change:

```
function Collection(){
   // assuming you're doing some initialization here, referencing "this"
}
Collection.prototype = new Storage();
```

to

```
function Collection(){
    var that = new Storage();
    // initialize whatever's necessary, using "that"
    return that;
}
```

or, if you aren't doing any initialization, just:

```
function Collection(){
    return new Storage();
}
```

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SgrzH/2/)

This turns `Collection` into a `Storage` factory, which prevents reusing the same `Storage` objects in the descendants.